# Jquery change row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code http://jsfiddle.net/Vds69/  I want to change current row in a table with new value, if I click on the button at the end of the row. Please help me to write action to change row

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid">                            
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary action-add-visual-feature"> + new visual feature </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger action-remove-visual-features"> Remove all features</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.action-remove-visual-features').on('click', function() {
    console.log("action-remove-visual-features");
    $('#table-visual-features tbody').html('');
});

$('.action-add-visual-feature').on('click', function() { 
    console.log("action-add-visual-feature");  

    $('#table-visual-features tbody').append('<tr><td>x</td><td>Numeric</td><td>Values to be mapped to the x-axis</td><td><button class="action-change">edit</button> <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger action-remove-visual-feature">remove</button></td></tr>');
});


$('#table-visual-features tbody').on('click', 'tr button.action-remove-visual-feature', function(e) {
    console.log("action-remove-visual-feature!!");
    console.log("e action  = ", e);
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `current row`?  Can you add more details

Comment: if I click on the button  at the end of row, I can change values in this row

Comment: @Joren your fiddle link isn't working

Comment: @Joren  your code it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML5 solution could be by appending the following function

```
$('#table-visual-features tbody').on('click', 'tr button.action-change', function (e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("changing")) {
                var $parentRow = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0);
                $(this).removeClass("changing");
                $parentRow.removeClass("changing");
                $(this).text("edit");
                /*$('.action-change').parents('tr').eq(0).find('td').attr("contenteditable","false");*/
                $parentRow.find('td').attr("contenteditable","false");
            } else {
                var $parentRow = $(this).parents('tr').eq(0);
                $(this).addClass("changing");
                $parentRow.addClass("changing");
                $(this).text("stop-edit");
                $parentRow.find('td').attr("contenteditable", "true");
            }
        });
```

CSS

```
tr.changing td{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vds69/8/

Otherwise, you will have to do something like the following,

*when editing*

1.append to your td input elements

2.input elements should get their value from the text of td elements

*finish editing*

1.get the values from input elements

2.remove the input elements

3.set the values as text to the td elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the HTML table manually.  *It has to done either programmatic or HTML wise*.

Here is better approach.

1) Enclose the **`td`** with **`textbox`**  like

```
<td><input disabled type="text" value="x"/></td>
```

Similarly apply to all the **`td`** s and **`disable`** them.

2) Then for **`edit`**, add a **`click`** functionality like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.action-change', function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Just enable the `textbox` for editing.

Check the working in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vds69/4/)

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hope something like this is what you want mate... Juz gave some static values for the time being..

```
$('#table-visual-features tbody').on('click','.action-change',function () {
    $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(0)').html('Visual');
    $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(1)').html('Alpahabet');
    $(this).parent().siblings('td:eq(2)').html('123');
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tRhHt/

Comment: i have updated the fiddle.Please check it mate... :)